# Excel, Trying Index, Match, to lookup values with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, match, lookup

I am trying to look-up values at cell locations using VBA, I have searched google and all over stackoverflow before asking this because I can't seem to get it to work.

The following is the code I am trying to use, note that budgetcode references a cell containing one of the codes in the first column and mo references a cell that contains a number (1-12) or contains a short code (ytd, 1qtr, 2qtr, 3qtr). Example is that I want to pull CAD-NS for February (2), and I should get 5666.40.

```
Function eBudgetl(budgetcode As String, mo As String)
eBudgetl = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Budget!G1:X5000"), _
   Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(budgetcode, Range("Budget!B1:B5000"), 0), _
   Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(mo, Range("Budget!G1:X1"), 0))
End Function
```

Here is part of the data I wish to lookup:

```
                                       1    2          3       4
CAD-NS      I   Net Sales           5264.0  5666.4  5614.9  5966.6
COSMAT      E   Material            6207.5  3660.0  3661.9  3560.9
COSDL       E   Direct Labor         610.4  105.3   167.1   123.6
CAD-MOIL    E   Indirect Labor       671.2  163.4   181.6   161.7
CAD-MOSAL   E   Salary Overhead      601.0  106.0   101.0   101.0
```

Here is the code in the cell that works, but I need to do in VBA. (The reason I need to do in vba is sometimes the budgetcode will contain 2+ references separated by a comma and I am going to use vba to separate them and look each up independently.)

```
=INDEX(Budget!$G$1:$X$5000,MATCH($F12,Budget!$B$1:$B$5000,0),MATCH(AN$1,Budget!$G$1:$X$1,0))
```

I appreciate any help very much, I have been at this for 3 days now.

Thanks,

Enoch

Comment: I think your issue is the `Types` of your function declaration.  Try `Function eBudgetl(budgetcode As Variant), mo As Variant)
`

Comment: Oh my goodness! I can't believe that worked! Seriously, Chris Neilsen, you just made my day!

Comment: Added as an Answer, with a bit of explanation and a few hints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the `Function` parameter types.

When you call your Function with `mo` = cell `AN1`, containing the *number* `1`, the Function type casts it to the *String* `"1"`, which doen't exisit in the range `Budget!$G$1:$X$1`, since these are also *numbers*.

The solution is to use `Variant` as the function paramters type.

To make debugging this type of error easier, try not to do too much in a single line of code.  Splitting the line into 2 x `Match` functions and an `Index`, would allow you to see the second match return an error.

Couple of other points:

- If your are calling this function as a **UDF** (ie called from a worksheet cell), it is better not to hard code the ranges.  As written, the calls to `eBudgetl` would not automatically recalculate when any of their data changes.
- the `Application` object has a version of `Index` and `Match` so the `WorksheetFunction` calls are not required

Refactored version to demonstrate:

```
Function eBudgetl(rData As Range, rBudCode As Range, rMo As Range, budgetcode As Variant, mo As Variant)
    Dim rw As Variant
    Dim col As Variant

    With Application
        col = .Match(budgetcode, rBudCode, 0)
        rw = .Match(mo, rMo, 0)
        eBudgetl = .Index(rData, col, rw)
    End With
End Function
```

Called as

```
=eBudgetl(Budget!$G$1:$X$5000,Budget!$B$1:$B$5000,Budget!$G$1:$X$1,$F12,AN$1)
```